# Suppose R is a reflexive relation over set A. Prove or disprove that R² is reflexive

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Question: Suppose R is a reflexive relation over set A. Prove or disprove that R² is reflexive

I can tell by the question, that if R is reflexive, then each element contains a self-loop.

So if relation R contained a self-loop, like { (1,1) } or something, R^2 would inevitably contain { (1,1) } as well. So can you theoretically do infinite self-loops, like if it were R^7 it would still contain { (1,1) }.

I am just unsure how to convey this idea in a proper proof format.

Answer (score 0):

For each $a\in A$, you want to prove that $a\mathrel{R^2}a$. But you know that $a\mathrel Ra$. And$$a\mathrel Ra\wedge a\mathrel Ra\implies a\mathrel{R^2}a.$$

Comment: So would something like this be sufficient?

Take ∈.

Suppose (a,a)∈R and another set (a,a)∈R. By definition, a relation composed with itself gives (a,a)∈2

Comment: That would be wrong because 1) $(a,a)$ is not a set (it's an ordered pair) and 2) you cannot talk about “another set $(a,a)\in R$” since $(a,a)$ is not *another* thing. It's its exact opposite: it's the *same* thing as before.

Comment: Okay, how about this. Suppose an arbitrary element (a,a)∈R, where a∈A and R is reflexive. Since ^2 is the compound relation R o R, if (a,a)∈R ∧ (a,a)∈R then (a,a)∈R^2 and is reflexive by definition. Apologies if I'm off base again. This stuff doesn't sit with me very well.

Comment: The sentence “Suppose an arbitrary element $(a,a)\in R$, where $a\in A$ and $R$ is reflexive” makes no sense. You were told that $R$ is reflexive, and so you don't write that you are going to suppos that. The first sentence could be “Suppose that $a$ is an arbitrary element of $A$”.